# Reorder array of objects based on attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, sorting

I have an array of objects, each with an 'id' and a 'name'. I'm retrieving an 'id' from the server and need to reorder the array starting from this id.

Example code:

```
var myList = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Joe'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Sally'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Chris'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Tiffany'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Kerry'
  }
];
```

Given an 'id' of 2, how can I reorder the array so my output is as follows:

```
var newList = [
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Chris'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Tiffany'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Kerry'
  },
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Joe'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Sally'
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function orderList(list, id){
  return list.slice(id).concat(list.slice(0,id));
}
```

Link to [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dankreiger/h1L44drk/1/)

Comment: Some assumptions in my data lend this solution to be the, seemingly, simplest solution. Other solutions provided also worked!

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You could *slice* the array at given index and return a new array using *spread syntax*.

```js
const myList = [{id:0,name:'Joe'},{id:1,name:'Sally'},{id:2,name:'Chris'},{id:3,name:'Tiffany'},{id:4,name:'Kerry'}];

const slice = (arr, num) => [...arr.slice(num), ...arr.slice(0, num)];

console.log(slice(myList, 2));
```

Comment: For a common case where ids can be not incremental you can also define `num` using `findIndex` for example, so that `num` and `id` are decoupled from each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
myList.sort(function(a,b){
 return a.id>2===b.id>2?a.id-b.id:b.id-a.id;
});

newList=myList;
```

http://jsbin.com/kenobunali/edit?console

Comment: You are allowed to use spaces :P

Answer (score 0):

You could splice the wanted part and use splice to insert it at the end of the array.

```js
var myList = [{ id: 0, name: 'Joe' }, { id: 1, name: 'Sally' }, { id: 2, name: 'Chris' }, { id: 3, name: 'Tiffany' }, { id: 4, name: 'Kerry' }],
    id = 2;
    
myList.splice(myList.length, 0, myList.splice(0, myList.findIndex(o => o.id === id)));

console.log(myList);
```

Answer (score 0):

using *es6* spread syntax

```js
var myList = [{ id: 0, name: 'Joe' }, { id: 1, name: 'Sally' }, { id: 2, name: 'Chris' }, { id: 3, name: 'Tiffany' }, { id: 4, name: 'Kerry' }],
id = 2;
var index = myList.findIndex(o => o.id == id);
var arr = myList.splice(0, index);
var result = [...myList, ...arr];
console.log(result);
```